# UIVIewController custom init method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I want to implement a custom initialization method for my UIViewController subclass to "replace" the initWithNibName method.

This is the code:

```
- (id) initWithMessage:(NSString *)message {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:@"ToolTip" bundle:nil])) {
        label.text = message;
    }

    return self;
}
```

The label is loaded from xib but at this point the reference to the label is nil (probably because the xib is not loaded yet?). Does anyone know a solution for that? Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but the correct answer is to use the `viewDidLoad` method to do any additional setup after the view has loaded.  The view is not loaded until it's needed, and may be unloaded when a memory warning is received.  For that reason, a view controller's view should not be touched in an `init` method.

Answer (score 2):

You should declare the label programmatically and initialize it within the init rather than do it from the nib.

This is how :

Assume `UILabel *label` is a class variable with `@property` and `@synthesize` defined for it.

```
- (id) initWithMessage:(NSString *)message {

    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:@"ToolTip" bundle:nil])) {
        label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        label.text = message;
        [self.view addSubView:label];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Release the label in the "dealloc" method.
Hope this helps.